# BIRT: Using Parameter in "group by" part of a SELECT

Tags: birt

I'm getting crazy with this problem:

I have got some Oracle SQL-Reports to redesign them with BIRT. The first things worked great but now there is a SELECT in the report that uses GROUP BY and for any reason it is not working in BIRT...

There is always an error like "GROUP BY clause is no GROUP BY expression.

The problem seems to be a parameter I'm using in the GROUP BY part because when I remove the parameter and pass any value in the query directly it is working.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Greetings

Comment: Seems i could find a workaround:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059412/birt-report-desing-in-eclipse-with-subreport-filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that I had to add the same parameter twice (one ? for the select, one for group by) and BIRT does not replace the ? with its value but using SQL Parameters and they are different also when they point to the same target. Or something like that. Using a "temp table" as explained in the linked topic (stackoverflow.com/questions/6059412/…) worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest leaving the SQL without a GROUP BY expression, and doing your grouping on the table or chart displaying the data.  When you add the grouping to the table, you should be able to define the group by expression as something like:

```
row[params["MY_PARAMETER"].value]
```

Passing a parameter to an Oracle group by will be difficult, because the grouped columns are the only ones which can appear directly in the SELECT clause (anything not in the group by can only appear inside a group function such as SUM, MIN, MAX, COUNT, etc.), so you would need to modify the SQL on the fly to add/remove columns in the SELECT clause.  This is possible, but difficult.

Comment: TY, but the select was not the problem. It worked fine when I fired it in SQL Developer. It just did not work in BIRT and with the "?" parameters.